# How to configure svn on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

1.
I m trying to install svn on eclipse by going on Help-Install New softwares but I am always getting error message you could not connect .so is there any another method ?
2.
Also I have downloaded subversion on terminal also I am able to do checkout ... but i am unable to commit any changes error says that 'https://svn.hostname.in/~dirmane/test' is not a local path
on typing following:
**svn commit https://svn.hostname.in/~dirname/test**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second question:

`svn commit` takes a path to your local working copy. The repository is not needed (in fact, not allowed) because your working copy is always associated with the same repository URL.

For example, if you have a working copy in C:\Temp\MyProject, which you got by doing `svn checkout http://example.com/svn/project C:\Temp\MyProject`, then you would commit any changes with `svn commit C:\Temp\MyProject`. Even better, change directories to C:\Temp\MyProject and you don't even need to specify a path: `svn commit`

Please only ask one question at a time...I have no idea about the first.